# Mysql Select unique record based on multiple columns and display only group and sum amount

Tags: mysql

Hi I am trying to query a table that conatains multiple duplicates on Code,Amount and Status How will I do this if I only one to get a result group according to the client_group name and get the sum of amount under that group

```
SELECT `client`.`client_group` 
,  FORMAT(SUM(`Data_result`.`Data_result_amount` ),2) as sum
FROM
  `qwer`.`Data_result`
  INNER JOIN `qwer`.`Data` 
      ON (`Data_result`.`Data_result_lead` = `Data`.`Data_id`)
  INNER JOIN `qwer`.`Data_status` 
      ON (`Data_result`.`Data_result_status_id` = `Data_status`.`Data_status_id`)
  INNER JOIN `qwer`.`client` 
      ON (`Data`.`Data_client_id` = `client`.`client_id`)
WHERE `Data_status`.`Data_status_name` IN ('PAID') AND  MONTH(`Data_result`.`result_ts`) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
AND YEAR(`Data_result`.`result_ts`) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
GROUP BY `client`.`client_group`
```

Result of said query:

[image]

Table

[image]

Comment: please add table schema and some sample data along with expected results. That'll be really helpful to solve this.

Comment: okay i'll include it wait .

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: I expect the output Sum of all amount in group not including duplicate data based on code ,amount and status

Comment: so sum for `ad` should be `9000`?

Comment: yes that's correct it should only be 9000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to distinct before run the 'sum' check whether this solve your problem

```
    SELECT `client_group` ,  FORMAT(SUM(`Data_result_amount` ),2) as sum from (
    SELECT DISTINCT `client`.`client_group` , `Data_result`.`Data_result_amount` 
    FROM
      `qwer`.`Data_result`
      INNER JOIN `qwer`.`Data` 
          ON (`Data_result`.`Data_result_lead` = `Data`.`Data_id`)
      INNER JOIN `qwer`.`Data_status` 
          ON (`Data_result`.`Data_result_status_id` = `Data_status`.`Data_status_id`)
      INNER JOIN `qwer`.`client` 
          ON (`Data`.`Data_client_id` = `client`.`client_id`)
    WHERE `Data_status`.`Data_status_name` IN ('PAID') AND  MONTH(`Data_result`.`result_ts`) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
    AND YEAR(`Data_result`.`result_ts`) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
    ) T
    GROUP BY `client_group`
```

you can check the query here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36a3f8/6

Comment: An error is appearing

Query : SELECT    `client`.`client_group`   ,  FORMAT(SUM(`Data_result`.`Data_result_amount` ),2) as sum(   SELECT DISTINCT `client`.`c...
Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sum(
 SELECT DISTINCT `client`.`client_group` , `Data_result`.`Data_result_amo' at line 2
Execution Time : 00:00:00:000
Transfer Time  : 00:00:00:000
Total Time     : 00:00:00:000

Comment: there was a mistake in bracket I edited the query have a check again. I didn't run the query so there may small mistake

Comment: Still an error appears does this syntax work on any mysql version?

Comment: @kkk the from key word was missing there http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36a3f8/6 check query here